# Maxima CAS - how to set something (to zero)

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima

I have a recursive equation for the quantities w1[k,n],w2[k,n] where k is either positive or negative integer, and n is a positive integer. The equation is the following:

```
eq1_1 : w1[ K, N ] + R*sum( sum( w1[ K-k, N-n ]*'diff( w2[ k, n-1 ], R ) + w2[ K-k, N-n ]*'diff( w2[ k, n-1 ], z ) + %i*k*( w1[ K-k, N-n ]*w2[ k, n ]*'diff( S, R ) + w2[ K-k, N-n ]*w2[ k, n ]*'diff( S, z ) ) , k, -n-1, n+1 ), n, 0, N ) = 0;
```

I write a rule

```
rule0: [N=0, K=0]
```

to write the first term. I just want to write it, not to solve it. I substitute this rule, set

```
simpsum:true
```

and I get as output an equation (am sorry but I'm not able to copy it here) with terms like w1[-1,-1] which should be equal to zero because n is positive. I tried to set it to zero with *subst, ratsubst* and *tellsimp* but neither of them worked (maybe I was using the wrong syntax). Is there a way to set those terms to zero, or even better to tell maxima not to write them even before it performs any computation?

Comment: What is the definition of `w1[k, n]` and `w2[k, n]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
w2[-1,0] : 0$ /* repeat as needed for other specific elements */
subst(rule0,eq1_1);
ev(%);
```

or, equivalently,

```
w2[-1,0] : 0$
subst(rule0,eq1_1),eval;
```